# get DateTime from mysql database into android sqlite

Tags: mysql, json, sqlite

I want to get data from mysql and store it in an android app. I could not find a  Date or Time field in android. I have to save it to sqlite database and keep it for the next app update.  In the next update I get the sqlite Date and check against the mysql database find out if there is a new post or not.

How can i get the data in the below loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i <count; i++) 
        {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            temp += 
                    "Name : " + json_data.getString("name")+ "\n"+
                    "Lastname : " + json_data.getString("lastname")+ 
                     date : " + //the DateTime       "\n";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although SQLite saves date as text or numeric, you can achieve features of mysql date/datetime in SQLite as well (indirectly).

Get datetime as per UTC timezone and save into SQLite db in milliseconds (long value) . SQLite takes `numeric` datatypes

Sample code:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Date date = format.parse(text);
long millis = date.getTime();
//your code - save datetime in milliseconds in SQLite numeric field
```

Indirectly you can avail all features of datetime in SQLite that mysql datetime has.

Comment: Thx but have i can get mysql date?? and change it to numeric and save it in sqlite?? I dont know where i have to save the DateTime that i get from json(String  or intiger).

Comment: @sajjadrezaee : you can use `java.sql.Timestamp` for storing `mysql timestamp`. Your question is not clear. please be specific.

Comment: I mean how i can get the DateTime from json? thx for responding by the way

Comment: @sajjadrezaee : what is the format of datetime in the json you receive?

Comment: actually i think i just can get a string of Date

Comment: @sajjadrezaee : Specifying the proper format of datetime string and setting proper timezone, you can easily get date. First you have to specify the format of date string that is like "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" as an example.